# Qt/C++: Icons not showing up when program is running in Kubuntu

Tags: c++, qt, qicon

I did everything what I need to do:

1. added an icon to resource file
2. initialized resource in main file: `Q_INIT_RESOURCE(images);`
3. set icon: `ui->action_New->setIcon(QIcon(":/images/about_me.png"));`

but still cant see an image when I compile and run my application (I use Kubuntu 12.04 and Qt 4.8.1). Here's a little test project: http://www27.zippyshare.com/v/45362924/file.html. What's wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: Where is the `QAction` used, in a `QMenu`?  Some DEs have to be explicitly told to display menu icons.

Comment: @cmannett85: yes, in `QMenu`

Comment: Do other applications (specifically Qt ones) in Kubuntu display menu icons?  Have you confirmed the image can be loaded correctly by trying to display it using a `QLabel`?

Comment: @cmannett85: I tried this: `ui->label->setPixmap(QPixmap(QString::fromUtf8(":/images/about_me.png")));` but still dont see the icon, I mean even on QLabel

Comment: Opps, it was my fault: `":/images/about"` solved everything, thanks :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pay attention to the `alias` bit in your `.qrc` file.

I prefer to set `<qresource prefix="/">` to keep it simple.

```
<RCC>
   <qresource prefix="/">
      <file alias="about me">images/about_me.png</file>
      <file alias="BSD License">otherfiles/LICENSE.txt</file>
      ... 
   </qresource>
</RCC>
```

This way you don't need to bother remembering the full path to use a resource

```
ui->action_New->setIcon(QIcon(":/about me"));    
this->setWindowIcon(QIcon(":/about me"));
...

QFile lfile (":/BSD License");
if(lfile.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly){
  ...
}
```

*Note: I'm not suggesting that using spaces in the aliases is a good or bad idea, but it certainly works.*